# Why is longitudinal slip necessary for car to be able to move?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

Suppose, the wheels of a car were to be replaced with solid concrete wheels, which do not deform,flex, etc. Would the car not be able to accelerate, take corners, etc ?

I do not understand why is it necessary for tires to develop slip for them to be able to move the car.

Comment: It would work fine, just a lot less smooth of a ride.

Comment: If so, when what's all the fuss about slip angles,slip Ratio, etc in the automotive world? There must be some problem with non-stretchable wheels.

Comment: Something should flex out the disturbances from the ground, the sooner the better.

Comment: I am guessing that what you really want to ask is "what if the wheels had infinite friction coefficient" in which case yes, you can never turn a corner because the wheels can never slip-twist with respect to the ground.  You need either to deform the tire or allow breaking traction.

Comment: Consider the solid steel wheels of a locomotive.  Can trains accelerate?